# XML File Translate with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a Swift Message encoded with SQL query using encoding="utf-16 - I used below code:

```
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Content AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')  AS XML) AS Content
```

Content of my XML structure looks like this:

[image]

**What I want to achieve**

I have a temporary table with multiple XML Files in this structure and I am trying to write a SQL query which will show me data in standard structure as a table

```
SELECT
    DateTimeCreated,
    t.value('(ApplicationHeaderBlock_Output/MessageType/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS MessageType,
    e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A/Date/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS XDTE,
    e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A//Date/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS RDTE
FROM 
    #MTFILE
CROSS APPLY 
    Content.nodes('//SWIFTHeader') AS a(t)
CROSS APPLY 
    Content.nodes('//SWIFT_CATEGORY5_MT566') AS b(e)

DROP TABLE #MTFILE
```

**Problem and what I want to achieve**

I'm not sure how to modify my current SQL query to achieve below results from XML file, because when I'm trying to specify path from XML file you can see it is same (from screenshot structure).

My point is to achieve and see result as below:

```
| XDTE        | RDTE           |
| --------    | -------------- |
| 20210310    | 20211012       |
```

If somebody could please advise?

Comment: Don't use pictures to show your data or code. Use plain text.

Comment: Extract `Qualifier` and pivot `Date` by `Qualifier` values

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - Hmm what do you mean?

Comment: @Serg Hmm can you wrote is simple example? not sure

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - Microsoft SQL

Comment: Is that Microsoft **SQL Server** - or are you using MS Access with SQL ?? Please be **precise**

Comment: Its Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, we need to assume that your `SELECT ...` statement is legit.

Here is your answer.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    DateTimeCreated,
    t.value('(ApplicationHeaderBlock_Output/MessageType/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS MessageType,
    e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A[Qualifier/text()="XDTE"]/Date/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS XDTE,
    e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A[Qualifier/text()="RDTE"]/Date/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS RDTE
FROM 
    #MTFILE
CROSS APPLY 
    Content.nodes('//SWIFTHeader') AS a(t)
CROSS APPLY 
    Content.nodes('//SWIFT_CATEGORY5_MT566') AS b(e);
```

Comment: This resolved my problem completely. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Cuchy, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: @Cuchy, please up-vote the following suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Answer (score 0):

Extract `Qualifier` and pivot. I use conditional aggregation for pivoting. Your DBMS may have  a special PIVOT tool.

```
select DateTimeCreated, MessageType,
     max(case when q='XDTE' then d end) as XDTE,
     max(case when q='RDTE' then d end) as RDTE
from (
    -- original query plus `Qualifier`
    -- hopefully it extracts data correctly
    Select DateTimeCreated,
       t.value('(ApplicationHeaderBlock_Output/MessageType/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as MessageType,
       e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A/Qualifier/text())[1]', 'DATE') as q,
       e.value('(SequenceC/Date_C_98A/Date/text())[1]', 'DATE') as d
    FROM #MTFILE
    CROSS APPLY Content.nodes('//SWIFTHeader') as a(t)
    CROSS APPLY Content.nodes('//SWIFT_CATEGORY5_MT566') as b(e)
) t
group by DateTimeCreated, MessageType
```